# How to put back HTMLElement into React component after the was (re)moved without React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We are wrapping a component library with React components, but in some cases the library manipulates the DOM tree in such a way that React will crash when trying to remove the React components.

Here's a sample that reproduces the issue:

```
function Sample () 
{
  let [shouldRender, setShouldRender] = React.useState(true);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={() => setShouldRender(!shouldRender)}>show/hide</button>
      { shouldRender && <Component /> }
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function Component () 
{
  let ref = React.useRef();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let divElement = ref.current;
    someExternalLibrary.setup(divElement);
    return () => someExternalLibrary.cleanup(divElement);
  });
  return <div ref={ref} id="div1">Hello world</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Sample />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);

let someExternalLibrary = {
  setup: function(divElement)
  {
    let beacon = document.createElement('div');
    beacon.id = `beacon${divElement.id}`;
    divElement.parentElement.replaceChild(beacon, divElement);
    
    document.body.append(divElement);
  },
  cleanup: function(divElement)
  {
    let beacon = document.getElementById(`beacon${divElement.id}`);
    beacon.parentElement.replaceChild(divElement, beacon);
  }
}
```

You can find [this sample on JSFiddle](https://jsbin.com/romigaz/edit?js,console,output).

The above sample will render the `Component` which integrates with `someExternalLibrary`.
The external library moves the elements from inside the React component somewhere else.
Even if the external library puts back the element at its original location using a beacon, React will still complain when trying to remove the Component when you click on the show/hide button.

This will be the error

```
"Error: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
    at removeChildFromContainer (https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js:10337:17)
    at unmountHostComponents (https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js:21324:11)
    at commitDeletion (https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js:21377:7)
    at commitMutationEffects (https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js:23437:13)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js:3942:16)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js:3991:18)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js:4053:33)
    at commitRootImpl (https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js:23151:11)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js:2764:14)
    at runWithPriority$1 (https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js:11306:12)"
```

An easy fix would be to wrap the existing HTML inside another DIV element so that becomes the root of the component, but unfortunately, that's not always possible in our project, so I need another solution.

What would be the best approach to solving this?
Is there a way to use a ReactFragment and re-associate the HTMLElement with the fragment during cleanup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanup function of useEffect, hence `someExternalLibrary.cleanup()`, is called **after** React has updated the DOM (removed the div from the DOM). It fails, because React is trying to remove a DOM node that `someExternalLibrary.setup()` removed (and `someExternalLibrary.cleanup()` will put back later).

In class components you can call `someExternalLibrary.cleanup()` **before** React updates the DOM. This would fix your code:

```
class Component extends React.Component { 
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.divElementRef = React.createRef();
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        someExternalLibrary.setup(this.divElementRef.current);
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        someExternalLibrary.cleanup(this.divElementRef.current);
    }
    render() {
        return <div ref={this.divElementRef} id="div1">Hello world</div>;
    }
}
```

The "extra div solution" fails for the same reason: Calling `someExternalLibrary.cleanup()` during the cleanup of useEffect() will mean the DOM has changed, but someExternalLibrary expects no change in the DOM. By using the class component with  componentWillUnmount, `someExternalLibrary.setup()` and `someExternalLibrary.cleanup()` will work with the same DOM.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you.
I was following guidance from the vendor when using `useEffect`, but using `useLayoutEffect` and the class-based components resolves the issue in my sample. 
I will try to apply this to the real project.

Comment: The div wrapping solution did work for some components in this component library we're integrating, but as you noted, doesn't in my sample. I'll have to look into where the different behavior comes from.

Comment: Updated JSBin in case it helps anyone: https://jsbin.com/jehadox/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't expect you to remove nodes that React has created. Treat nodes created by React as read-only. Instead you should:

> wrap the existing HTML inside another DIV element

However you don't explain why that isn't feasible:

> but unfortunately, that's not always possible in our project, so I need another solution.

Without that info, which is your real issue, a solution cannot be given.

Comment: For some components to work properly, the HTML structure has to be as expected by the component library's CSS and JS. Wrapping with another node breaks this in some cases.

Even if it would work, I'd like to avoid creating meaningless nodes, but at least I would be able to move on for now.

Comment: "For some components to work properly, the HTML structure has to be as expected by the component library's CSS and JS." => This doesn't explain why you have to remove the div created by React. --- "Even if it would work, I'd like to avoid creating meaningless nodes" => It isn't meaningless, because otherwise React crashes.

Comment: The CSS and JS of the external library won't work as expected if I do wrap it in a div. I can't achieve the expected HTML structure for this component library.